# 42082 Rough terrain crane

Tags: technic

Crane can not be pushed forward or backward. It seems the front and back wheels want to move in different directions.I the rear wheels are lifted off the ground crane can be moved forward and backward and the engine will turn over. The same thing applies if the front wheels are lifted off the ground. The steering operates on all four wheels as it should.
Can anyone give me some clues as to what might be wrong.
Thanks, Tony.